# Retrieve all hashtags from a tweet

Tags: twitter

Is it possible using the [Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/) to retrieve a list of all hashtags present within a single tweet?

For example, let's say I have a tweet (let's say it has an ID of 12345) with the following text:

> Hi.  I love #stackoverflow because it's #superawesome.  #fb

Is there an API call that will give me back #stackoverflow, #superawesome, & #fb when I give it an ID of 12345?

Or do I just have to parse the text of the tweet myself?

Comment: If you do have it to parse it yourself, you could always look into lifting the code from a hashtag-aware Twitter client.

Comment: Good point.  I'll keep that in mind as I go forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use a regular expression in your language of choice

```
   #\S+
```

should match any hash, beginning with # and made of a string of characters. It stops at the first space.

If you want to exclude any trailing symbol and have a letter as the last char :

```
#\S*\w
```

This expression should work in most of the regex engines I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Tweet Entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities). Just include `&include_entities=1`.

Comment: This would actually be much better than parsing the text to see if there are '#' symbols .. since the new API offers a 'entities' object with hashtags, mentions, media ...

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter API does not have any functions specifically designed for hashtags.  You'll need to parse the text on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Although @ialphan's solution is good, if you want to sort hashtags with occurance just use this answer in similar question:
[Retrieve all hashtags from a tweet in a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060601/retrieve-all-hashtags-from-a-tweet-in-a-php-function/16609221#16609221)