# Retrieve all hashtags from a tweet in a PHP function

Tags: php, regex, twitter

I want to retrieve all hashtags from a tweet using a PHP function.

I know someone asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952835/retrieve-all-hashtags-from-a-tweet), but there is no hint how exactly to implement this in PHP. Since I'm not very familiar with regular expressions, don't know how to write a function that returns an array of all hashtags in a tweet.

So how do I do this, using the following regular expression:

```
#\S*\w
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
$tweet = "this has a #hashtag a  #badhash-tag and a #goodhash_tag";

preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/", $tweet, $matches);

var_dump( $matches );
```

*Dashes are illegal chars for hashtags, underscores are allowed.

Comment: Note that ```$matches``` gives an array of sized 2. Both of the elements have same strings. Also not unicode supported.

Comment: This expression is one of the best I've found.

Comment: This helped me, thanks so much! :) Quick question, why does it give an array of size 2, with duplicate elements?

Comment: `#test#` is not a hash tag.

Comment: Note: this regexp will only match english words (so, ie #gøypålandet won't be matches as a hashtag)

Comment: U probably need an mbyte safe regex function, not in a position to test it here, sorry, else try the @trante solution.

Comment: this expression does not support all languages. works only for classic latin characters.

Comment: It gives the correct result but don't know why does it give an array of size 2.

Answer (score 39):

I created my own solution. It does:

- Finds all hashtags in a string
- Removes duplicate ones
- Sorts hashtags regarding to count of the existence in text
- Supports unicode characters

  ```
  function getHashtags($string) {  
      $hashtags= FALSE;  
      preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/u", $string, $matches);  
      if ($matches) {
          $hashtagsArray = array_count_values($matches[0]);
          $hashtags = array_keys($hashtagsArray);
      }
      return $hashtags;
  }
  ```

Output is like this:

```
(
    [0] => #_ƒOllOw_
    [1] => #FF
    [2] => #neslitükendi
    [3] => #F_0_L_L_O_W_
    [4] => #takipedeğerdost
    [5] => #GönüldenTakipleşiyorum
)
```

Comment: +1 for this a really nice solution to the question, thank you.

Comment: @trante Does that still work? The returned array is empty for me. How does the string needs to look like or encoded?

Comment: This not work with some unicode characters. eg. in Thai #รองเท้า will get only #รองเท
The vowel of Thai language not included.

use @minaz method below worked!

Comment: Emoji support: `/(#\w+|\p{So})/u`

Answer (score 18):

Don't forget about hashtags that contain unicode, numeric values and underscores:

```
$tweet = "Valid hashtags include: #hashtag #NYC2016 #NYC_2016 #gøypålandet!";

preg_match_all('/#([\p{Pc}\p{N}\p{L}\p{Mn}]+)/u', $tweet, $matches);

print_r( $matches );
```

\p{Pc} - to match underscore

\p{N} - numeric character in any script

\p{L} - letter from any language

\p{Mn} - any non marking space (accents, umlauts, etc)

Answer (score 8):

Try this regular expression:

```
/#[^\s]*/i
```

Or use this if there are multiple hash tags joined together (eg. #foo#bar).

```
/#[^\s#]*/i
```

Running it PHP would look like:

```
preg_match_all('/#[^\s#]*/i', $tweet_string, $result);
```

The result is an array containing all the hashtags in the Tweet (saved as "$result" - the third argument).

Lastly, check out this site. I've found it really handy for testing regular expressions. http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

**EDIT**: I tried your regular expression and it worked great too!

**EDIT 2**: Added another regex to extract hash tags, even if they're consecutive.

Comment: this works better as it supports other languages too. The only problem is it doesn't separate adjacent hashtags. This is my quick solution: `$wholeText = str_replace('#', ' #', $wholeText);`

Comment: @SerdarDeğirmenci You could also add a hash into the above regex to achieve the same thing without using `str_replace`. eg. `/#[^\s#]*/i`

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function:

```
function get_hashtags($tweet)
{
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all('/#\S*\w/i', $tweet, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```