# Extracting Twitter hashtag from string in PHP

Tags: php, twitter, hashtag

I need some help with twitter hashtag, I need to extract a certain hashtag as string variable in PHP.
Until now I have this

```
$hash = preg_replace ("/#(\\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=$1\">#$1</a>", $tweet_text);
```

but this just transforms hashtag_string into link

Comment: Are you looking to get the hashtag or remove it? Or both? All you're doing there is matching a hashtag pattern and then replacing with the exact same string.

Comment: You are just replacing the hashtag with the same thing actually...

Comment: For one, `preg_replace` does just what the name implies: *it replaces something* ... `preg_match` is more semantically appropriate for what you're trying to accomplish. Also, it'll be easier to assist if you'll post a basic example of the source string you're pulling from and an example of exactly what you want to pull out from that source string.

Comment: The only Fully working answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16609221

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) to identify the hash and capture it to a variable, like so:

```
$string = 'Tweet #hashtag';
preg_match("/#(\\w+)/", $string, $matches);
$hash = $matches[1];
var_dump( $hash); // Outputs 'hashtag'
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AlrHgb)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was helpful.. keep up good work guys. peace

Comment: Two flaws, first does not accept underscores, and second, ignores unicode chars

Comment: @Webinan `\w` matches underscore. For unicode, add the `u` flag to the end of the regex.

Comment: @nickb Oh, third, only extracts the first hashtag in the string :)

Comment: @Webinan That's not the scope of the OP. This answer applies to the question that was originally asked, nothing more.

Comment: @nickb It might have been better to also show an example of allowing underscore and unicode characters instead of just mentioning it in a comment

Answer (score 3):

I think this function will help you:

```
echo get_hashtags($string);



function get_hashtags($string, $str = 1) {
    preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/',$string,$matches);
    $i = 0;
    if ($str) {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
            $count = count($matches[1]);
            $keywords .= "$match";
            $i++;
            if ($count > $i) $keywords .= ", ";
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
            $keyword[] = $match;
        }
        $keywords = $keyword;
    }
    return $keywords;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As i understand you are saying that
in text/pargraph/post you want to show tag with hash sign(#) like this:- #tag
and in url you want to remove # sign because the string after `#` is not sended to server in request so i have edited your code and try out this:-

```
$string="www.funnenjoy.com is best #SocialNetworking #website";    
$text=preg_replace('/#(\\w+)/','<a href=/hash/$1>$0</a>',$string);
echo $text; // output will be www.funnenjoy.com is best <a href=search/SocialNetworking>#SocialNetworking</a> <a href=/search/website>#website</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Extract multiple hashtag to array

```
$body = 'My #name is #Eminem, I am rap #god, #Yoyoya check it #out';
$hashtag_set = [];
$array = explode('#', $body);

foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $hashtag = [];
    if (!empty($row)) {
        $hashtag =  explode(' ', $row);
        $hashtag_set[] = '#' . $hashtag[0];
    }
}
print_r($hashtag_set);
```

Comment: nice solution A++

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_match_all()`](https://php.net/preg_match_all) PHP function

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!\w)#\w+/', $description, $allMatches);
```

will give you only hastag array

```
preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/', $description, $allMatches);
```

will give you hastag and without hastag array

```
print_r($allMatches)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract a value in a string with [preg_match function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php)

```
preg_match("/#(\w+)/", $tweet_text, $matches);
$hash = $matches[1];
```

preg_match will store matching results in an array. You should take a look at the doc to see how to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non Regex way to do it:

```
<?php

$tweet = "Foo bar #hashTag hello world";

$hashPos = strpos($tweet,'#');
$hashTag = '';

while ($tweet[$hashPos] !== ' ') {
 $hashTag .= $tweet[$hashPos++];
}

echo $hashTag;
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/JlvfvIOa)

*Note: This will only pickup the first hashtag in the tweet.*