# how to extract all #Tags and User tag from string in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, tags

I have an **input field** where **Username Tage** like **@abd123,@abc1**, and some Topic Tags like **#CurrentNews,#NewLife** on same input field.

here my job is to catch all tagged name that starts with @ and # and put on separate array for a look into their **DataBase** table. 
so it being very complicated for me. so please tell me the easiest solution.

it's before I used **explode()** method for this. but it was not a good idea.

the value i am getting like this way from request

```
$allTags =  @abc1,@abvc321, #NewAge , #CurrentNews
```

it should be after process.

```
$userTag = ["@abc1","@abvc321"];
$topicTag = ["#NewAge ","#CurrentNews"];
```

Comment: Why do you say *"but it was not a good idea"*? `explode()` should work fine to separate the string into an array, then check the first character of each value in the array and move it to `$userTag` or `$topicTag`.

Comment: Dear Lewis **explode()** just break and convert array. but here the user putting some other symbol like white space between two tags.  so that it was difficult to manage that. so i was looking regular exp. for this solution.

Comment: Makes sense. If the format is predictable, then `explode()` can work, but yeah, allowing for dynamic content would require regex.

Comment: yes. i can not validate this from front-end... in future, i can do..

Answer (score 3):

Adapting the answer from [Extracting Twitter hashtag from string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006518/extracting-twitter-hashtag-from-string-in-php) to also capture the user tags, this uses both in the same regex to produce 2 lists.  The filters (`array_filter()`) are used to tidy the arrays up (when one contains a user tag, the other will be empty)...

```
$string = '@abc1 xxx,@abvc321, #NewAge , #CurrentNews';
preg_match_all("/(#\\w+)|(@\\w+)/", $string, $matches);
$topicTag = array_filter($matches[1]);
$userTag = array_filter($matches[2]);

print_r($userTag);
print_r($topicTag);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => @abc1
    [1] => @abvc321
)
Array
(
    [2] => #NewAge
    [3] => #CurrentNews
)
```

Comment: thank you very much.  you saved a lot of time.  i need one more question. so can you send me your mail in **p1608088@gmail.com**? because i asked that question here but my score went down.so I do not want to lose my rating. that is form Multi-auth based program solution...

Answer (score 0):

Dear **Nigel Ren** I made little change in your solution. because **$userTag** was in object format. so it datatype going change. that does not affect in **foreach**. but I try to make both into array format.

```
    $string = $req->user_tags;
    preg_match_all("/(#\\w+)|(@\\w+)/", $string, $matches);
    $topicTag = array_values(array_filter($matches[1]));
    $userTag = array_values(array_filter($matches[2]));
```

after this my result

```
 [
   [
     "@pankaj",
     "@pawan"
   ],
 [
   "#tag",
   "#tag2",
   "#tage3"
 ]
]
```