# Locate hashtags

Tags: php

I have a string that contains text, and in several places there will be a twitter-style hashtag. I want to find them and create a seperate variable where all of them are seperated by spaces. I also want to convert all of the hashtags in the original string into links. Example:

```
$string = "Hello. This is a #hashtag and this is yet another #hashtag. This is #another #example."
```

after function:

```
$string_f = "Hello this is a <a href='#'>#hashtag</a> and this is yet another <a href='#'>#hashtag</a>. This is <a href='#'>another</a> <a href='#'>example</a>";

$tags = '#hashtag #another #example';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060601/retrieve-all-hashtags-from-a-tweet-in-a-php-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find all of the hash tags, use a regex and [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all), and do the replacement with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$regex = '/(#[A-Za-z-]+)/';
preg_match_all( $regex, $string, $matches);
$string_f = preg_replace( $regex, "<a href='#'>$1</a>", $string);
```

Then all of the tags are in an array in `$matches[1]`:

```
$tags_array = $matches[1];
```

Then, convert that to a space-separated list with [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) and [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique):

```
$tags = implode( ' ', array_unique( $tags_array));
```

And you're done. You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/z7b9AG) that `$tags` and `$string_f` are:

```
"#hashtag #another #example"
"Hello. This is a <a href='#'>#hashtag</a> and this is yet another <a href='#'>#hashtag</a>. This is <a href='#'>#another</a> <a href='#'>#example</a>."
```

For other characters in the hashtag (for example, digits), modify the `$regex` appropriately.

**Edit:** However, this can be improved in efficiency if you use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) and a closure so you only have to execute the regex once, like so:

```
$tags_array = array();
$string_f = preg_replace_callback( '/(#[A-Za-z-]+)/', function( $match) use( &$tags_array) { 
    $tags_array[] = $match[1];
    return "<a href='#'>" . $match[1] . "</a>";
}, $string);
$tags = implode( ' ', array_unique( $tags_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a little nifty regular expression?

```
preg_match_all("/#[\w\d]+/", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
unset($matches[0]);
$tags = implode(" ", $matches);
```