# Count all hashtags in a string - PHP

Tags: php, string

Is there a way to count the hashtags in a string and receive a a number as a ending result?

```
$string = 'This is a #0 and #1 works like #2';

$count_hashtags = count('#',$string);

echo $count_hashtags;

//Output: "3"
```

Comment: use  substr_count($string, "#");

Comment: @Piyush: it won't work `"foo #bar baz######"` string contains only one hashtag, whereas your solution will return more.

Comment: @zerkms: Yes, I did. `echo substr_count($string, '#');` returns 3, which is what the OP wanted (as indicated by `Output: "3"` in the question) and solves the problem.

Comment: @Amal Murali: `"foo #bar baz######"` --- for this the correct answer must be 1. Does your solution return 1 for the given string?

Comment: @zerkms: You're right - it doesn't. But it is unclear what is the exact requirement here. If the OP is looking for finding all the Twitter-style hashtags, this would be a more fitting duplicate: [Retrieve all hashtags from a tweet in a PHP function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3060601/1438393). (It's not an exact duplicate, but the idea is very same. It needs just `$count_hashtags = count($matches[1]);` to get the number.)

Comment: In foo #bar baz###### case need to use regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = 'This is a #0 and #1 works like #2';   // Result : 3
$string2= 'foo #bar baz######';                 //  Result : 1

preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/", $string, $matches);
echo count($matches[0]);
```

**Edit:**
You could then put it inside a function

```
function countHashTags($string)
{
    if(preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/", $string, $matches))
        return count($matches[0]);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: "*A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word". The definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For example, in the "fr" (French) locale, **some character codes greater than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by \w.***" — [source](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php). Otherwise, good answer, +1.

Comment: The capturing group isn't required either, since you're not doing anything with it.