# PHP : How to count the number of URLs, hashtags and user_mentions in a Twitter tweet

Tags: php, twitter

I want to count the number of URLs and #HashTags posted in a tweet. I am using PHP to scan the twitter feeds. 
Is it possible to get the count of URLs and #hashtags posted in a twitter tweet ?

How do I get this ?

EDIT:

I tried this code

```
preg_match_all('/#\S*\w/i', $tweet, $matches);
var_dump( $matches );
```

Output:

```
array(1) {                      //count1
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "#GoodMorning"
  }
}
array(1) {                      //count2
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "#HelloWorld"
  }
}
array(1) {                      //count3
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
array(1) {                      //count4 
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Expected Output:

Number of hashtags = 2 
Number of Urls = 3 (if any)

Thank you for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve all hashtags from a tweet in a PHP function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060601/retrieve-all-hashtags-from-a-tweet-in-a-php-function)

Comment: I am getting it in the array form. How to get it in a simple numeric digit ? like,  Number of hashtags = 3.

Comment: try using  `count($name_of_your_array);` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: ok got it for hashtag. but how do I do it for URLs and user_name_mentions ?

Comment: I would recommend you to read up on preg_match_all and regex (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), you should be able to to all those things with more calls to preg_match_all or a clever regex.

Comment: Here the count() function counts all the array in the list. Is it possible to get only those counts which has hashtags ? this results me count=4, but i have only 2 hashtags

Comment: The other ones seem to not contain anything. You could just iterate over the array and look at the size of the values. If not empty, add 1 to the count of hashtags, if empty, add 0.

Comment: ya got it . thank you. why is my question down voted? is it not the way to ask ? I am new to this site

Comment: Someone probably thought that it was too broad, or that you didn't properly search for a duplicate before asking. I'd say, don't worry too much about it. Since my comments helped you answer the question, I'll post an answer containing them. If you think that I helped, please select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of the answer in [Retrieve all hashtags from a tweet in a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060601/retrieve-all-hashtags-from-a-tweet-in-a-php-function), just adding the counting of the ouput.

```
$tweet = "this has a #hashtag a  #badhash-tag and a #goodhash_tag";
preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/", $tweet, $matches);
count($matches[0]);
```