# PHP get characters after # in descriptions

Tags: php

How can I make each product identification number mentioned in the below description into variables, excluding the # pulling them from the description in PHP?

> Two 9-dram clear styrene tubes with snap-on caps, 1 x 2-3/4″ I.D.
>   (25.2 x 68mm), are supplied as containers. Additional or replacement
>   tubes **#8909** are available.
>
> As a safety precaution, BioQuip recommends using the **#1135Y** HEPA
>   filter with this aspirator.
>
> Also see **#1135X** aspirator syringe bulb. It allows users to aspirate
>   specimens without inhaling particulate matter.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: The answer here is what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060601/retrieve-all-hashtags-from-a-tweet-in-a-php-function

Comment: @Funk Doc: actually the user needs a modified version of the official answer b/c user wishes to exclude the hashtag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could use this regular expression (regex):

```
/#(\w+)/
```

along with [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) which performs a global search for data matching a regex, and stores what it finds in an array, as follows:

```
<?php

$str = "Two 9-dram clear styrene tubes with snap-on caps, 1 x 2-3/4″ I.D. (25.2 x 68mm), are supplied as containers. Additional or replacement tubes #8909 are available.

As a safety precaution, BioQuip recommends using the #1135Y HEPA filter with this aspirator.

Also see #1135X aspirator syringe bulb. It allows users to aspirate specimens without inhaling particulate matter.";

$pat = "/#(\w+)/";
if ( preg_match_all( $pat, $str, $matches )) {
  $popped = array_pop( $matches );
  list( $alpha, $beta, $gamma ) = $popped;
  echo "The IDs are as follows:\n\n$alpha\n$beta\n$gamma\n";  
}
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/vdGqt)

This regex specifies a hashtag followed by parentheses to "remember" one or more word characters, i.e.  numeric or alphabetical data. By  enclosing this expression with parentheses, the hashtag will be excluded and the remaining data stored in `$matches[1]`. Once $matches contains data, you are done unless you wish to utilize `$matches[1]` to create three unique variables and optionally display their values.

You could dispense with using a regex and use the following code with the above-indicated value of `$str`:

```
<?php
$ids=[];
$a = explode("#",$str);
array_shift( $a );
$ids = array_map( function( $e ) {
                  return explode(" ",$e)[0];
                  },$a);

print_r($ids);
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/QGt5X#output)

By avoiding preg_match_all(), the second solution may offer the advantage of better performance. Alternately, you can split the array returned by explode() into a list that only includes relevant information, and then create an array of the list variables for array_map(), as follows:

```
<?php

$ids=[];
list(,$a,$b,$c) = explode( "#",$str );
$ids = array_map(function( $e ) {
                  return explode(" ",$e )[0];
                  },[ $a,$b,$c ]);

print_r( $ids );
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/qb7Ml#output)

Comment: If you look at the tooltip on the downvote arrow, it is much milder than the "policy" you've cited. All it says is that the answer is unclear or not useful. That's the only "condition" that there is for a downvote, and users are fundamentally free to vote however they wish. Votes are never "corrected", unless they've been cast fraudulently. Complaining about downvotes in comments almost never works out well, and is really just considered noise, so please don't do it. One upvote more than makes up for one downvote. You are not so bad off here.

Comment: The policy is not up to me to change. It has been this way ever since the site was launched back in 2008. Personally, I don't see anything wrong with it, either. Votes are essentially democratic. I don't want to have a system where moderators (or anyone else) goes around auditing votes for "accuracy". A downvote is just a signal that someone thought your answer could be improved.  If you're confident that your answer is correct and helpful, then there's nothing more to be done.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Use [Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). This regex I wrote `(\#.+?)` (note the space at end) matches the product id numbers. Try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/sAjb9X/1). To use the regex with PHP use [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

> preg_match_all
>
> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7) preg_match_all — Perform a global regular
>   expression match
>
> Description
>
> int preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array
>   &$matches [, int $flags = PREG_PATTERN_ORDER [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )

### Code

```
<?php
    $pattern = "/(\#.+?) /";
    $string = "Two 9-dram clear styrene tubes with snap-on caps, 1 x 2-3/4″ I.D. (25.2 x 68mm), are supplied as containers. Additional or replacement tubes #8909 are available. As a safety precaution, BioQuip recommends using the #1135Y HEPA filter with this aspirator. Also see #1135X aspirator syringe bulb. It allows users to aspirate specimens without inhaling particulate matter.";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
    print_r($matches[0]);
?>
```

### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => #8909
    [1] => #1135X
    [2] => #1135Y
)
```

Once, you have the array, you can access the codes, that were found, by grabbing them from `$matches[0]`. For example to print the first match, just do this:

`$matches[0][0]`

The second match:

`$matches[0][1]`

and, if you want to get really fancy you can print it out into a table:

```
<?php
    $pattern = "/(\#.+?) /";
    $string = "Two 9-dram clear styrene tubes with snap-on caps, 1 x 2-3/4″ I.D. (25.2 x 68mm), are supplied as containers. Additional or replacement tubes #8909 are available. As a safety precaution, BioQuip recommends using the #1135Y HEPA filter with this aspirator. Also see #1135X aspirator syringe bulb. It allows users to aspirate specimens without inhaling particulate matter.";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

    echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: 
    collapse;border-color: silver;'>";  
    echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";  
    echo "<td width='150' align='center'>Product Codes</td>";  
    echo "</tr>";

    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) 
     { 
      echo '<td width="150" align=center>' . $match . '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
     }
?>
```

This would output:

[image: Product code table]

### Try it out

[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ec82ee7212e272fc401de5b2a3944d5821ca726)

Answer (score 0):

Without regex, you could split the string by space and add a substring of each word beginning with `#` to an array of results.

```
foreach (explode(' ', $description) as $word) {
    if ($word[0] == '#') $products[] = substr($word, 1);
}
```

I think it's safe to assume this will be slower than regex, though.